# Angularjs ng-change is not firing

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I am developing Angularjs Application. I have two dropdownlist boxes. Whenever i select something in first dropdown then based on the value of firstdropdown, second firstdropdown will load(Cascading dropdownlistbox). I am using Ajax calls for binding data to dropdownlist .
Below is my index.html where i have two dropdownlistboxe's.

```
<select ng-model="selectedMake" ng-options="b for b in list" id="brand" ng-change="getModel(selectedMake)">
 <option value="">-- Select a Make --</option>
 </select>
 <select ng-model="selectedModel" ng-options="b for b in Modellist" id="brand">
 <option value="">-- Select a Model --</option>
 </select>
```

This is my controller code.
 var arrMakes = new Array();

```
$http.get("http://localhost:4739/api/AutoLease/GetVehicleMake").success(function (data) {
        $.map(data, function (item) {
            arrMakes.push(item.MakeName);
        });
        $rootScope.list = arrMakes;
    }).error(function (status) {
    });
    $rootScope.getModel = function (selectedMake) {
        debugger;
        var arrModel = new Array();
        $http.get(url + 'api' + '/AutoLease/' + selectedMake + '/GetVehicleModel').then(function (response) {
            $.map(data, function (item) {
                arrModel.push(item.ModelName);
            });
            $rootScope.Modellist = arrModel;
        });
    }
```

I am able to load first dropdown. In first dropdown i have getModel function in ng-change event. This event is not firing. I am not getting any error message too. May I know something i am missing here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Create Plunker pls

Comment: I think you don't need to pass the selectedMake in getModel function. Just access that in the function as $scope.selectedMake will have the selected value and please provide any jsfiddle or plunker so you will get your answer quickly and other can understand easily. Try to set $scope instead of $rootScope.

Comment: Thanks. Please find here. https://plnkr.co/edit/Wx0z64cLkRm129KTrj9T?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $scope instead of $rootScope

```
$scope.getModel = function (selectedMake) {
        debugger;
        var arrModel = new Array();
        $http.get(url + 'api' + '/AutoLease/' + selectedMake + '/GetVehicleModel').then(function (response) {
            $.map(data, function (item) {
                arrModel.push(item.ModelName);
            });
            $rootScope.Modellist = arrModel;
 });
```

also there could be another reason that value of the selected is same , so that ng-change does not get fired. check your option values if they are different.

Comment: Thanks but i passed $rootScope as below  angular.module('RoslpApp').controller('HomePageController', ['$rootScope','$http', '$translatePartialLoader', '$translate', 'toastr','cfg',
        function ($rootScope, $http, $translatePartialLoader, $translate, toastr,cfg)

Comment: does it reaches the method?

Comment: $rootScope.getModel is not getting fired.

Comment: using $rootScope is a bad practice

Comment: @NiranjanGodbole found a solution?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141698/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-niranjan-godbole).

Comment: @Sajeetharan when using `then` function for get response should be use`response.data`

Comment: @HadiJeddizahed yeah right! i dont think that's the problem here. anyway your answer provide the same

Answer (score 0):

try this. when using `then` for get response it should be like this

> response.data

```
 $http.get(url + 'api' + '/AutoLease/' + selectedMake + '/GetVehicleModel').then(function (response) {
        $.map(response.data, function (item) {
            arrModel.push(item.ModelName);
        });
        $rootScope.Modellist = arrModel;
    });
```

[<kbd>**Demo**</kbd>](http://plnkr.co/edit/CE9K0tkbK4dCG95KbA7E?p=preview)

Comment: @Niranjan Godbole please test this answer

Comment: Thanks but problem is  $rootScope.getModel not working.

Comment: please see this demo

Comment: this has nothing to do with the OP problem (using $rootScope instead of $Scope) but this is HEAVLY recommended because success is depreceated

Answer (score 0):

AS others advice you use `$scope` instead of `$rootScope`

But if you have to use it for other raison ( like sharing a global variable ) you have to prefix with `$root` in view like this

`<select ng-model="selectedMake" ng-options="b for b in list" id="brand" ng-change="$root.getModel(selectedMake)">`